# HTable is not getting invoked through JAVA API

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

First of all thanks for viewing my question. Currently, I have installed **hbase-1.2.3** and **hadoop-2.7.3** in a Linux box. When executing the jps, I could see the below process running,

```
11015 HQuorumPeer
25843 NameNode
26173 SecondaryNameNode
25985 DataNode
11130 HMaster
11267 HRegionServer
11961 Jps
```

Even, I could login to hbase shell and provide commands to view my tables. Problem is I am trying to call the HBase table through my standalone java program and it stucks there. Below is the output I am seeing when I execute the program. I am not seeing anything there in the other logs (master, region, zookeeper).

Below is my sample program,

```
  Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
  config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","localhost");
  config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");

  // Instantiating HTable class
  System.out.println("Entering");
  HTable table = new HTable(config, "test_venkat");
  System.out.println("Exiting");
```

### Logs

```
Entering
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Oct 06, 2016 12:11:53 PM org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper <init>
INFO: The identifier of this process is 11863@servername
```

It hangs after this and it is not printing the Exiting statement. Can anyone please help me on this? What could be the reason? Appreciate your help